# How can I parse a simple xml file from the www on my local WAMP server?

Tags: javascript, xml, wamp

I am using WAMP on localhost to learn web development. I am trying to learn XML, and have chosen the simple XML http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KAJZ.xml as a starting point. If I put the file on my localhost server, it works fine. However, the following does not work:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KAJZ.xml",false);

xmlhttp.send(); 
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

If I put a simple write statement after   xmlhttp.send(); it does not execute.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: Does it return a null or empty string? Does it return an incorrect result? What is the content of `xmlDoc` after reading the response?

Comment: No code after the following line is executed: xmlhttp.send();

Comment: xmlDoc never gets a value because the code quits running. Seriously though, I know for a fact this is as easy a question as possible. Why is nobody answering?

Answer (score 0):

If you use this code, and the javascript debugger in your browser you will see that the site does return a readyState = 4 but never returns a status 200 i.e. it never send any data.

Are you sure you dont need an account or something like that so that it allows a response to your call?

```
<?php
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doit()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KAJZ.xml",false);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        debugger;
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <button onclick="doit();" >Click</button>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got it working by programmatically creating the xml file on my server. This answer was helpful for my understanding though.